# trigger to convert lead automatically creating multiple object records

Tags: apex, trigger

I have trigger on Lead object which is creating Contacts, records in Relationship objects, affiliation objects etc.

On lead creation my trigger is working perfectly but I want to convert lead automatically before creating all the records. right now if I use database.lead converts then its creating two contacts but I want only one contact to get created.

Can anyone helps me out in this issue.

```
trigger ContactCreationFromLead on Lead (After insert, after Update) {
//trigger to create contact, relationship, affiliation records from lead.
List<Lead> em = new List<Lead>();
List<Contact> conInsertList = new List<Contact>();
List<hed__Affiliation__c> affiliation = new List <hed__Affiliation__c>();
List<hed__Relationship__c> relation = new List<hed__Relationship__c>();
List<hed__Affiliation__c> affiliationListToBeInserted = new List<hed__Affiliation__c>();
List<String> listEmail = new List<String>();
List<String> listname = new List<String>();
Set<String> otherProgramsValueSet = new Set<String>();
if(trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate){
for (Lead em : Trigger.new) {
    if(em.Email != null){
        listEmail.add(em.Email);
    }
    if(em.What_is_your_primary_program_of_interest__c != null ){
        listname.add(em.What_is_your_primary_program_of_interest__c);
    }
    if(em.Other_Programs_of_Interest__c != null){
        otherProgramsValueSet.addAll(em.Other_Programs_of_Interest__c.split(';')) ; 
    }
}
}
//to catch the account Id that matches the lead primary program of interest
//account name should match with primary program of interest picklist values
List<Account> account = [SELECT Id,Name,Pardot_Program_Name__c from Account WHERE Pardot_Program_Name__c = :listname];
String record;
for(Account acc : account){
    record = acc.Id; 
}
List<Contact> cem = [SELECT Id, Email FROM Contact WHERE Email = :listEmail];
String cemail;
for(Contact ce : cem){
    cemail = ce.Email;
}
//code to create contact for student if form is filled by student
for(Lead ld : Trigger.new) {
    if (ld.Email != cemail && ld.Parent_or_guardian__c == false) {

        Contact cnt = new Contact();

            cnt.FirstName = ld.FirstName;
            cnt.LastName = ld.LastName;
            cnt.Email = ld.Email;
            cnt.RecordTypeId = '012P00000005ZDpIAM';
        conInsertList.add(cnt);
    }
    //code to create contacts for parent and student if form is filled by parent
    else{
        if(ld.Email != cemail && ld.Parent_or_guardian__c == true ){
            Contact cnt1 = new Contact();
            cnt1.RecordTypeId = '012P00000005ZDuIAM';
            cnt1.FirstName = ld.Parent_First_Name__c;
            cnt1.LastName = ld.Parent_Last_Name__c;
            cnt1.Email = ld.Parent_Email__c;
        conInsertList.add(cnt1);
            Contact cnt2 = new Contact();
            cnt2.RecordTypeId = '012P00000005ZDpIAM';
            cnt2.FirstName = ld.FirstName;
            cnt2.LastName = ld.LastName;
            cnt2.Email = ld.Email;
            cnt2.HasOptedOutOfEmail = ld.Email_Opt_Out__c;
        conInsertList.add(cnt2);
        }
    }
}
if(conInsertList.size()>0){
    INSERT conInsertList;
    List<Id> conInsert = new List<Id>();
    //catch the inserted contact ids to create relationship record
    if(conInsertList.size()>1){
    for(Integer i = 0, s = conInsertList.size(); i < s; i += 2){
        //creates relation record by catching current student and parent record id's
        hed__Relationship__c hedrel = new hed__Relationship__c();
        hedrel.hed__Contact__c = conInsertList[i + 1].Id;
        hedrel.hed__RelatedContact__c = conInsertList[i].Id;
        hedrel.hed__Type__c = 'Parent';
        relation.add(hedrel);
        //creates affiliation record if filled by parent
        hed__Affiliation__c hedaff = new hed__Affiliation__c();
        hedaff.hed__Account__c = record;
        hedaff.hed__Contact__c = conInsertList[i + 1].Id;
        hedaff.hed__Primary__c = true;
        affiliation.add(hedaff);
        //creates affiliation records for other programs multi select picklist field
        for(Account acc : [select id from account where name in : otherProgramsValueSet]){
affiliationListToBeInserted.add(new hed__Affiliation__c(hed__Account__c= acc.Id,
                                                       hed__Contact__c=conInsertList[i + 1].Id));
        }
    }
    }
    else{
        //creates Affiliation record if filled by student only
        if(conInsertList.size()==1){
        for(Integer i = 0, s = conInsertList.size(); i < s; i += 2){
        hed__Affiliation__c hedaff = new hed__Affiliation__c();
        hedaff.hed__Account__c = record ;
        hedaff.hed__Contact__c = conInsertList[i].Id;
        hedaff.hed__Primary__c = true;
        affiliation.add(hedaff);
            for(Account acc : [select id from account where Pardot_Program_Name__c in : otherProgramsValueSet]){
affiliationListToBeInserted.add(new hed__Affiliation__c(hed__Account__c= acc.Id,
                                                       hed__Contact__c=conInsertList[i].Id,
                                                       hed__Role__c='Student'));
            }
    }
    }
    }
    insert relation;
    insert affiliation;
    insert affiliationListToBeInserted;
}
LeadStatus convertStatus = [Select MasterLabel from LeadStatus where IsConverted= true limit 1];

 List<Database.LeadConvert> leadConverts = new List<Database.LeadConvert>();
for (Lead lead: Trigger.new) {
if (!lead.isConverted && lead.Status == 'New' ) {
Database.LeadConvert lc = new Database.LeadConvert();
String opportunityName = lead.Name;
lc.setLeadId(lead.Id);
lc.setSendNotificationEmail(false);
lc.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(true);
lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);
leadConverts.add(lc);
}
}
if (!leadConverts.isEmpty()) {
 List<Database.LeadConvertResult> lcr = Database.convertLead(leadConverts);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database.convertLead is going to create a new contact, unless you modify the LeadConvert object to use an existing contact Id.

See here https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dml_convertLead.htm

> setContactId(Id)
>   Sets the ID of the contact into which the lead will be merged (this contact must be associated with the account specified with setAccountId, and setAccountId must be specified). This value is required only when updating an existing contact.

So what you can do is:

1) create your contact, as you are doing right now.

2) get the contact Id

3) pass the contact id to the leadConvert class

Alternatively, don't create a contact manually, and let the lead conversion to do it for you.

Comment: Hi CommonCoreTawan, thanks for helping me out in this, Can you help me out how and where I can modify the code to achieve it.

Comment: Can't help you with that I'm afraid. Are you able to read code?

Comment: yes, but I really don't know how to pass the contact Id into lead conversion which I created

Comment: is it possible, during lead conversion if lead email exists in contacts then update contact instead of creating new contact